# How do i find the number of a 4×4 matrix with each row and each column having two 1s and two 0s?

Tags: combinatorics

(I have seen a similar question for n×n matrix. However the answer to it just points to an a link (http://oeis.org/A001499) without explaining how to get the result through combinatorics)

How do i find the number of a 4×4 matrix with each row and each column having two 1s and two 0s?

My approach:

I noted that
0011
0011
1100
1100

Follows the rule.

So i tried the fact that swapping any two rows and/or any two columns also satisfies the result.

But in this approach i am getting a lot of repetitions i cant handle.

Comment: Do you want to find all such $4\times4$ matrices, count them, just find a specific example (which you've done), etc. ? What is the actual question you'd like answered because I'm not sure.

Comment: **HINT:** This question can be solved using P.I.E such that firstly place the ones into each rows such that $C(4,2)^4=6^4 =1296$ ways. There are $1296$ possible matrix which have $2$ ones (and so zeros) in each rows. However , it contains some unwanted configurations such that the columns contains more than $2$ ones or less than $2$ ones. Here  , the P.I.E gets in the deed (and a little cumbersome for this question)

Comment: Why don't you say "yes" to the question of Logan M ?

Comment: @Salmon Fish What is P.I.E. (Principle of Independent Events ?) ?

Comment: This question : math.stackexchange.com/q/35019/305862 is about the number of such matrices ; in particular, the accepted answer is connected to the site you mention oeis.org/A001499

Comment: @LoganM yes i made a pathetic error of language

Comment: @JeanMarie yes indeed ot is the question i was talking about. I am trying to find the answer with a particular value of n